# Servlets not recognizing sessions from android app

Tags: android, session, servlets

I have and android app which talks with the sevlets. The login is sessioned, I am able to generate sessionid and sessionname and pass it down to the app. I am setting the sessionid and sessionname in the login page, like this

```
session.setAttribute("sessionid",session.getId());
session.setAttribute("sessionname","name");
```

I am receiving those things from the app. But in the servlet when I do

```
String id = session.getAttribute("sessionid");
```

It returns `null`.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

**Update:**

For subsequent request I am sending the sessionid and sessionname as a header in httppost.

Like this.

```
sessionname has the sessionname value received from the server.
and sessionid has the sessionid value received from the server.
httppost.setHeader("Session",sessionname+"="+sessionid);
```

and in the server side i am getting those things like this

```
String session = request.getHeader("Session");
String sessionname  = session.substring(0,session.indexOf("="));
String sessionid = session.substring(session.indexOf("="));
```

So now i have got both sessionname and sessionid in those variables, i check them against the session object like this

```
if(session.getAttribute("sessionname").equals(sessionname) && session.getAttribute("sessionid").equals(sessionid))
```

this is where i get null. Not for the variables i have taken but for the session object method, 
`getAttribute("sessionname") and getAttribute("sessionid")` 
returns null

Comment: Show and tell us some more code. The problem is obviously not in those snippets, but on where they are called and at what point :)

Comment: You want to use [`HttpSession#getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId()). The session id is not stored as an attribute in the session attributes, it's part of the object,

Comment: *"For subsequent request I am sending the sessionid and sessionname as a header in httppost."* Why didn't you show in your question how you're doing that? Now nobody can point out your mistake. Further, a log of the HTTP traffic would also be helpful (e.g. Fiddler, Wireshark, etc). I *guess* that you're not fully aware of how HTTP sessions work in general. The statement *"sending the sessionid and sessionname as a header"* is at least very suspicious. You normally need to set only one header, namely the one of the `JSESSIONID` cookie. You don't need to set one header per attribute or so.

Comment: I have updated the question with code snippets. Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("http://mydomainname.com");
```

Get cookie of this connection, and in your connection add this cookie, this will provide it with the session of your connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the session id in the url like ....;jsessionid=xxx

Comment: I have no problem in sending the session attributes. I am able to read them on the server but the session objects returns null on using getAttribute("sessionname"). Thanks for replying.